# Redirect stdout to a file in python not entirely working

Tags: python, stdout, io-redirection, mpi4py

I have following setup:

**parent.py**:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

for i in range(10):

    print(something)

    child_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn(sys.executable, "child.py", maxprocs=9)
    child_comm.Disconnect()
```

**child.py**:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open("analysis_log.txt", "a")

# code related to running a solver

sys.stdout.close()
```

The child.py is running a solver and prints a lot of stuff on terminal. I want to redirect only the output from `child.py` file. So, I cannot use `python parent.py >> analysis_log.txt`. Instead, I am assigning stdout to a file. But, the output is not redirected to the file and it still prints in terminal. The solver provides a python interface for working with it but it is using compiled fortran files for performing calculations, along with fortran write and print statements to output on terminal.

So, I am guessing that setting `sys.stdout` will only redirect the python print statements and not fortran stdout. I checked lot of other questions on this topis on stack overflow, but most of them suggest using `open` or `contextlib.redirect_stdout`. I tried the context redirection also, but it still prints in the terminal.

So, how to resolve this problem? Why is it that terminal redirection (`>>`) works, but setting sys.stdout is not working fully?

Please help!

Python: 3.8.13

Comment: `sys.stdout` only changes, well, Python code that uses `sys.stdout`; a shell redirection replaces file descriptor 1, so it impacts software that isn't written in Python at all; software that writes direct to the descriptor, etc.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, which covers doing an in-place replacement of FD 1.